# Все варианты слова в нижнем, верхнем регистре и т.д

Tags: php

Есть слово "саша", как можно реализовать функцию, которая выдаст список всех вариантов написания этого слова? т.е. Саша, САша, САШа, САША, сАША и т.д.

Comment: А если не секрет - зачем это вам?

Comment: @vp_arth Я так догадываюсь, при входе пользователя он хочет проверять на все эти значения и заходить.

Comment: Он удалил комментарий, ему нужна регистронезависимая версия html_entity_decode, поэтому он решил сгенерировать все варианты и заменять через strtr

Comment: Если на самом деле вам нужно сравнить ввод вне зависимости от регистра с известным словом, то просто переведите этот ввод в тот регистр, в котором храните свое слово. Если же не знаете, в каком храните, то переводите и ввод и это слово  в один и тот же регистр (например, нижний).

Comment: я уже реализовал функцию которую мне тут заминусили, хотя она на 100% выполнила свою задачу и на массивах в сумме 600т. ключей создала новые на 4млн. за 10 секунд, я решил свою задачу и в ней нельзя менять регистр входных данных, т.к. это путь ссылки, который регистрозависимый

Comment: @Василий А что, разве ответ на PHP тоже оказался непонятен?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Сделать рекурсивную функцию, на каждом уровне рекурсии делать два вызова, добавляя к текущей строке очередной символ в нижнем регистре и в верхнем

   ```
   function build($k, $s, $src) {
     if ($k == strlen($src)) //достигнута длина строки{
     {  
       echo $s."\n";
     }
     else {
       $c = $src[$k]; 
       $u =  strtoupper($c);
       $l = strtolower($c);
       build($k + 1, $s.$u, $src);
       build($k + 1, $s.$l, $src);
     }   
   }

   build(0, "", "abc");
   ```
2. Перебрать целые числа от 0 до 2^len-1, рассмотреть биты каждого числа, ставя в соответствие единичному биту символ верхнего регистра, нулевому - нижнего

   ```
   i = 9 = 1001b = > СашА
   ```

Comment: Вы точно перепутали метки.

Comment: Это [псевдокод](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/636546/176064). Перевести на php можете самостоятельно.

Comment: Нет, не перепутал, это действительно псевдокод

Comment: @MBo, метка php, а не Псевдокод, Давайте будем кидаться псевдокомандами, чтобы новичкам вообще не понятно было, что там вы пишите и на каком языке. Зачем так умничать, если можно было не писать псевдокод, а раз вам - это так просто сделать, потратить время на рабочий пример, оформив в вопросе.

Comment: Работать будет только на англ, в вопросе слово, точнее имя, **саша** =). А тут уже придется делать `mb_*` функции и делать через `preg_split`разбивку в массив по буквам, а тут уже будет немного по другому.

Comment: @And, вы неправы. SO - это не про биржу готовых ответов. MBo привёл хороший ответ, в котором абсолютно понятно, как решать поставленную задачу. Не нужно поддерживать потребительского отношения: «не хочу думать, дайте чтобы оно сразу работало». С другой стороны, вместо колкостей «зачем так умничать», вы могли бы написать свой ответ.

Comment: @And Дяденька, я не настоящий сварщик ©, и псевдокод приводил, потому что продемонстрировать принцип я могу, но качественный код на PHP, учитывающий все нюансы, вряд ли напишу. Про mb_* и preg_split я увидел в гугле при написании, но мне неочевидно было, насколько приличные те примеры, и правильно ли вообще это использовать.